# Laravel PHP - upload_max_filesize ignored when trying to upload file

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

I have an app with Laravel in my own server. I've built a page with an input file upload and my server is configured to accept a max file size of 1MB. When I send the request to my controller, the upload starts and returns a `OK 200` status even if the file is lower or greater than 1MB.

I've configured my `php.ini` with these settings:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 1M


; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 500M
```

If the file is greater than 500MB or all the uploaded files are greater than 500MB I get a `PostTooLargeException`, due to my `post_max_size` config. I don't know why I get an exception from `post_max_size` and not from `upload_max_filesize`. Also, I don't if this is something related with Laravel or with my PHP, but I've tested multiple values in the `upload_max_filesize` config, restarting the HTTPD service daemon each time I applied the new config and still not working.

I cannot find any information about it referencing Laravel bugs/errors or even PHP bugs/errors.

A `phpinfo()` call shows the information correctly, but it is not working. My example code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
...
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file-upload" />
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="fileUpload">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
...
<script>
$('*[data-toggle="fileUpload"]').on('click', function() {
    var file = $('#file-upload[name="file-upload"]').prop('files')[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data, jqXHR, status) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The server side controller code has nothing, only a `return true;`

Let me know if you need any further information.

Current setup: Laravel 5.4, PHP 7.0

Best regards,
D.

Comment: there may be several `php.ini` in your system and it's hard to diagnose which one is being used. So change all of them

Comment: I only use one `php.ini`, which is stored at `/etc/php.ini`. I manually "built" my server. Installing httpd and php in a CentOS from scratch. No extra packages or LAMPP used

Comment: Modify the php.ini with this max_execution_time=120,max_input_time=60,max_input_nesting_level = 64,max_input_vars = 1000,memory_limit=300M,log_errors_max_len=1024,post_max_size=300M,upload_max_filesize=250M,max_file_uploads=20 and restart the service

Comment: I have unlimited memory_limit and unlimited log_errors_max_len. The rest is applied by default with the values you provided, and still not working

Comment: The default value are less i have increased the value of mentioned variables.make sure you update each of them and restart the services

Comment: As I said, almost all variables had the same value per default, but where commented. I removed the `;` on them and the others were with a value of `-1`, which is unlimited. Still not working. Only the max_execution time was increased from 60 to 120, but as I said, it is still not working.